# Get metadata of SOAP webservice

Tags: .net, soap

Have url of webservice, kinda:

https://test.com/abc

Open in web browser:, getting error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
<soap:Body>
<soap:Fault>
<soap:Code>
<soap:Value>soap:Sender</soap:Value> 
</soap:Code>
<soap:Reason>
<soap:Text /> 
</soap:Reason>
<soap:Detail>
<gwerror:errorInfo xmlns:gwerror="http://test.com/error/faultdetail">
<gwerror:errorCode>0x00000000</gwerror:errorCode> 
<gwerror:description /> 
<gwerror:descriptionDetail>Request without message body blocked.</gwerror:descriptionDetail> 
<gwerror:errorPlace>KITS.GW.ERR</gwerror:errorPlace> 
</gwerror:errorInfo>
</soap:Detail>
</soap:Fault>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

How i can get metadata of this service?
Or i dont need metadata?
How can i call this service from my .net app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a response message from server,if i am not wrong . Error code and message means , then there is a problem with your request SOAP message and there is nothing inside  ....  tag, please check request message again.